# Material UI example code not running

Tags: node.js, material-ui

I have downloaded the browserify example of Material UI ( https://github.com/callemall/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example/tree/f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8) and run according to the documents.
1. npm install
2. npm start

The npm install accumulates all node_modules but when I run npm start it gives following error:

```
[17:57:22] Starting 'setWatch'...
[17:57:22] Finished 'setWatch' after 94 μs
[17:57:22] Starting 'browserify'...
[17:57:22] Bundling app.js...
[17:57:22] Starting 'markup'...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: watch /home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/package.json ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1234:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1262:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/node_modules/watchify/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:473:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/home/xyz/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! material-ui-example-browserify@0.15.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the material-ui-example-browserify@0.15.0 start script 'gulp'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the material-ui-example-browserify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs material-ui-example-browserify
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls material-ui-example-browserify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/xyz/workspace/practice/material/material-ui-browserify-gulp-example-f893414ed2f48864f909a9d537b9f332c65488d8/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: The link you provided returns a 404 on Github. I cannot find an NPM package of that name, and the https://github.com/callemall page does not list it either. Could it just be an old package that is no longer supported?